# How do you roll back to the previously deployed version with capistrano?

Tags: capistrano

I tried using "cap rollback" but I get the following error:

> $ cap rollback
>
> the task `rollback' does not exist

Is there some additional setup that I need to do to get rollbacks to work?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Just found the answer here http://github.com/leehambley/railsless-deploy:

> cap deploy:rollback

Comment: Good resource. This one appears to have a couple more methods and more  documentation: http://capitate.rubyforge.org/recipes/deploy.html

Comment: What if I want to rollback not just to the previous deploy, but to some earlier one? Is there some argument or environment variable to pass to this command specifying which version I want to rollback to?

Comment: Is there any way to rollback to some specific version? [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30484093/2945616) is not working in Capistrano 3.

Answer (score 52):

If you're using different environments (e.g. staging, production) using the multistage gem (e.g. you have `require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'` in your deploy.rb file) then Capistrano defaults to staging. So, to roll back a production environment you would do:

```
cap production deploy:rollback
```

and, assuming you've got the defaults set, this would roll back staging:

```
cap deploy:rollback
```

Worth knowing if you're using different environments and wondering why it's not working for production.

Answer (score 15):

**simple roll back:**

```
$ cap deploy:rollback
```

**rollback to specific version:**

```
$ cap deploy:rollback -s previous_release= [path to previous release under releases folder ]
```

Answer (score 9):

Actually it is

```
cap deploy:rollback:code
```

**deploy:rollback** may rollback to a previous revision, not necessarily a previously deployed revision.

Comment: I realize significant time separates this answer from the accepted answer, but according to the code for the `rollback` namespace, as of today, the default action for `cap deploy:rollback` does the same thing as a code rollback **plus** a restart. Ref: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb#L325