# Rollback code in Capistrano.. for a PHP Project

Tags: php, deployment, capistrano

I'm looking for an easy way to go back to the previous release if something goes wrong with the last realease in **Capistrano**

Is there any command like "cap goback" to **undo** the last **deploy**? (thus updating the current symlink to it's **old location**)

Is this built-in or I just have to make a task myself?

Here's my recipe:

```
set :user, "root"
set :use_sudo, false

set :domain, "www.domain.info"
set :deploy_to, "/home/beta2"
set :current_dir, "public_html"

set :scm, "git"
set :repository,  "git@github.com:user/ac.git"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :scm_verbose, true
set :git_enable_submodules, 1

role :web, domain
role :app, domain


task :link_shared_directories do     
  run "ln -s #{shared_path}/photos #{release_path}/photos"
end    

after "deploy:update_code", :link_shared_directories
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the standard capistrano setup then take a look at these tasks:

cap deploy:rollback
cap deploy:rollback:code

If you have customized deployment tasks then you will have to roll your own.

Comment: Thanks mate.. is there anyway I could see the task code of those tasks?

Comment: you would have to checkout the gem directly and browse the source. http://github.com/jamis/capistrano.git  Then find the strategy file that matches the repository you are using.  Good luck!

Comment: If you want to see all the available Capistrano commands, type 'cap -T'

Answer (score 0):

[Someone asked a similar question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496998/how-do-you-roll-back-to-the-previously-deployed-version-with-capistrano) and answered it himself, but it appears the link he posted is broken.

Anyway, there's a project on GitHub, called [Railsless Deploy](http://github.com/leehambley/railsless-deploy/tree/master), which seems to include a task for **rollback**.

I confess I've just started out with Capistrano this weekend, so apologies if that's not what you're looking for.